# How can I export an FBX with Textures

Tags: texturing, export

I cannot seem to get my model to export as an FBX with the textures intact. Is there a tutorial that shows how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What render engine are you using?

Comment: For which application? — [Helvetica](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_Sans_MS)

Comment: I think this would only work if you have textures added to Blender Internal Materials.  You should provide more information.  You can upload a .blend file to PasteAll.org and paste the link here.  You should definitely remove the tutorial request from your question, you're question is likely to be closed because of that.

Comment: I am wanting to export an FBX from Blender for use within Unreal Engine 4. However, I cannot figure out how to do this. I am able to export the model, but it has no texture information. This leaves me having to re-apply all of the materials one-by-one. Thanks!